# Can I safely rely on hostname only ever being undefined for local files (i.e. navigating to a local file)?

Tags: javascript, hostname, window.location

I'm creating a web extension that runs on every page but only works in certain contexts. Here is the isSupported() method:

```js
// return a boolean value that is true if the domain/page is supported, element name matches
// supported types, and content is marked as spell checkable
function isSupported (node, hostname) {
  const supportedNodeNames = ['TEXTAREA', 'DIV']
  const supportedDomains = ['mail.google.com', 'github.com']

  if (node.spellcheck && node.isContentEditable) {
    if (node.nodeName === 'TEXTAREA') {
      return true
    }

    if (supportedNodeNames.contains(node.nodeName) && supportedDomains.contains(hostname)) {
      return true
    }
  }

  return false
}
```

This code unfortunately stops the extension from running on my local test page, i.e. when the URI is `file:///home/username/github/multi-dict/test_page/test-page.html`

Can I safely rely on `window.location.hostname` being undefined* and allow the extension to run when it is? I checked the docs over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) and [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#dom-hyperlink-hostname) but it wasn't quite clear to me under what exact contexts the hostname would be undefined.

Thanks in advance!

*It's actually an empty string, left in original description for reader/answer context. So the question is - can I safely rely on `window.location.hostname` only ever being empty for a local file the browser has opened - no local webserver is running.

Comment: Is it really `undefined`, or is it just the empty string `""`?

Comment: Why not just run a server on localhost? It's insanely easy these days...

Comment: Safe against what? But no, I wouldn’t rely on that. (Can’t say offhand what would be able to break it – `<iframe sandbox>` and other originless things maybe? – but it’s very uncomfortable for any sort of security purpose.) Server on localhost or maybe checking for `file:///` seem like better directions.

Comment: Hey Ry I've updated the title now to be clearer, good catch. I mean safe as in hostname being an empty string _only_ in the context of a local file being accessed minus a local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hostname` is defined as a **string** ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hostname), [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#location)), so it can't have the value `undefined`. It's an empty string (`""`), not `undefined`, on every browser I've tried (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge). If you think it's `undefined` on some browsers, you could just do a falsy check:

```
if (location.hostname) {
    // It has a non-blank value
} else {
    // Its value is falsy (probably "", perhaps undefined)
}
```

But I don't think it's ever `undefined`. From the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#dom-location-hostname):

> The hostname attribute's getter must run these steps:
>
> 1. If this `Location` object's relevant `Document` is non-null and its origin is not same origin-domain with the entry settings object's origin, then throw a "SecurityError" DOMException.
> 2. If this `Location` object's url's host is `null`, **return the empty string.**
> 3. Return this `Location` object's url's `host`, serialized.

*(my emphasis)*

The host of local URLs is `null`, so the emphasized part of Step 2 applies.

Comment: My mistake, I should of checked the type of the value - you are right that even when just pointing the browser to a file, it is indeed a string (an empty one in this case). I have updated the question now so it's hopefully a little clearer - I'm interested in knowing if the location.hostname will only ever be empty for a locally served file. Took the advice from Ry's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791666/can-i-safely-rely-on-hostname-only-ever-being-undefined-for-content-served-local#comment103865279_58791666) and am checking location protocol as well.

Comment: @GrayedFox - That's the only scenario I'm aware of that makes the origin `null`, so Step #2 above should apply. But definitely look at the protocol (aka scheme).